# Placeholder doesn't show

Tags: html, css, web, placeholder

Guys I've read everything here about that topic already, but I still can't figure out why my Placeholder is not showing up. Hope you can share your expertise and tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="input-block-level search-query" placeholder="Enter your name" required="">
```

It's just not showing up in any browser.  Thanks is advance!

Comment: What browser are you using? Remember that certain browsers such as IE6–9, Opera 10.1 and FF <4.0 do not support the `placeholder` attribute: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this code to your placeholder show on this input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function add() {if($(this).val() == ''){$(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder');}}
    function remove() {if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')){$(this).val('').removeClass('placeholder');}}
    if (!('placeholder' in $('<input>')[0])) { 
        $('input[placeholder]').blur(add).focus(remove).each(add);
        $('div').submit(function(){$(this).find('input[placeholder]').each(remove);}); 
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" name="search" class="input-block-level search-query" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this link which will give us a good idea about how we fix placeholder problem it will use jquery and it will be a good solution.
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
And here is the full jquery code 
// Released under MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
var input = $(this);
if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
input.val('');
 input.removeClass('placeholder'); }
}).blur(function() {
var input = $(this);
if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
input.addClass('placeholder');
input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
 }
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
$(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
var input = $(this);
if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
input.val('');
}
})
});
```